# Regarding Ternary condition

Tags: apex

[image]

```
If(isNewQuote){

        proxyAccount=accountId;
        }

            else if(proxyQuote.Id!=Null)
           {

            proxyAccount=proxyQuote.Id;
        }
            else{

if(proxyQuote.Account_c != null && (accountid == null && proxyQuote.Id == null))

{

    proxyAccount=proxyQuote.Account_c;

        }

            }
```

Can you please help me to write in this ternary condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this you can try

```
ID ProxyAccount =
isNewQuote ? accountId : (proxyQuote.Id!=Null)
? proxyQuote.Id : (proxyQuote.Account_c != null && (accountid == null && proxyQuote.Id == null))
? proxyQuote.Account_c : NULL;
```

Comment: getting this error as  Compile Error: Expecting ')' but was: '!' and also i think last line  proxyQuote.Account_c : NULL;  ,null is not needed i guess

Comment: It should be there as per your conditions. Post the screenshot of same.

Comment: okay can you resolve the error?

Comment: This is the logical expression please send me the datatype of same I can construct the same.

Comment: i have added screenshot

Comment: What's the datatype for ProxyAccount ?

Comment: public Id proxyAccount;

Comment: I have edited the ternary formula. Is that work for you?